# Prettier vscode extension not support Django template tags {% tag %}

Tags: python, html, django, visual-studio-code

Prettier visual studio code extension not support  Django template tags {% tag %}

now How can I fix this?

Do I have to disable Prettier extension  for html files or is there another solution؟؟

issues 5581 in github = [No Django template tags support](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5581)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**February 2022**

Based on @Al Mahdi's comment: Prettier does not support `prettier.disableLanguages` option anymore. Therefore, to ignore certain files you have to create a .prettierignore file akin a .gitignore file (for people who use Git). The file lives in the root folder of your project. [Source of my examples below.](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#html)

To ignore one file you could type in a particular filename:

```
# Ignoring just one file
my_cool_html_file.html
```

Or you could use a blanket statement:

```
# Ignoring all html files
*.html
```

There is also the pragma option (`<!--prettier-ignore-->`) which lets you ignore bits and pieces of code from particular files. Suppose in your `my_cool_html_file.html` you want to not have Prettier format some lines in it, you could:

```
<!-- prettier-ignore -->
<div         class="x"       >hello world</div            >

<!-- prettier-ignore-attribute -->
<div
  (mousedown)="       onStart    (    )         "
  (mouseup)="         onEnd      (    )         "
></div>

<!-- prettier-ignore-attribute (mouseup) -->
<div
  (mousedown)="onStart()"
  (mouseup)="         onEnd      (    )         "
></div>
```

**July 2020 (old answer)**

You can do two things:

1. Disable Prettier on HTML files by adding this command in the
   'settings.json' file:

   ```
   "prettier.disableLanguages": ["html"]
   ```

   This will ensure, if you have enabled it, VS Code's inherent HTML formatting.

**OR**

2. You can install a Django extension like [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=batisteo.vscode-django). However, the problem with this extension is that it disables VS Codes inherent HTML intellisense (which I personally like).

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my case, my document was formatted as django-html so in order for @analytical_prat to work I had to use:
 "prettier.disableLanguages": [
    "html",
    "django-html"
  ]

Comment: "prettier.disableLanguages" is no more supported. Use .prettierignore file config instead

Answer (score 14):

When using `"prettier.disableLanguages": ["django-html"]` I got the below warning in VS Code:

> This feature is no longer supported. Instead, configure VS Code
> [default
> formatters](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#default-formatter)
> or use .prettierignore.

I followed the instructions and was able to disable prettier in `django-html` files by adding the following to `settings.json` :

```json
"[django-html]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
}
```

This tells VS Code to not run automatic formatting when saving `django-html` files. However, if you are using other formatters along side pretty, and you only want to prevent pretty from formatting, then this might not be an optimal solution.

**Alternative method:**

The other method that the warning suggested was to use a `.prettierignore` file. You simply place the file in your source root directory and specify the files, directories, patterns, etc, that you would like pretty to ignore. The syntax is the same as a `.gitignore` file. You can read more about it [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html).

Comment: I like this method. However I did not have an option to specify the file type as `django-html`. I had to install the [Django](https://github.com/vscode-django/vscode-django) extension so my templates could be detected correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Like @ahimsauzi pointed out, the solution is

```
"prettier.disableLanguages": ["django-html"]
```

Just disable `"django-html"`.

Answer (score 6):

I don't Know if it works for you, but I can solve the problem by not using prettier in django templates, installing **djlint** as dev dependence in my project(I'm using pipenv you can install it as system wide package) and installing the **djlint extension** in vscode.

After install djlint we need to configure our vscode

```
"[html]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "monosans.djlint"
},
"[django-html]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "monosans.djlint"
},
```

If you don't want to include that configuration in the global settings, you can add them in the workspace settings.

I hope my solution works for you

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a .prettierignore file in your project directory.
2. Add *.html in the .prettierignore file.

Now prettier will ignore all the html files in your current project.

Answer (score 1):

Alert: Hack ahead.

I add an empty HTML comment `<!>` after template blocks.
Prettier rightly identifies it as HTML comment and adds a line break.